# limit of the sequence $a_n=n\left[\sin\left(\frac{1+n^3}{n^2}\right)-\sin n\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I started by writting

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n &=& n \left[\sin\left(\frac{1+n^3}{n^2}\right)-\sin\, n\right]=\frac{\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^2}+n\right)-\sin\, n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}} \\
    &=&\frac{2\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cos\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^2}+2n\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

after putting 2 in the denominator of the denominator, I got stuck.

Solution's manual of the book follows my reasoning but writting the result after using the trigonometric identity was different and I did not understood it. Did I do something wrong?

[image: solution manual]

Comment: $\sin \left (\frac{1+n^3}{n^2} \right ) =\sin \left ( \frac{1}{n^2} +n \right )$.

Comment: ok this was typing error

Comment: You should have $ \displaystyle{\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+2n\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$

Comment: You also didnot divide by $2$ when you used the identity $\sin p- \sin q$

Comment: oh yeah... maybe the quarantine is driving me displicent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic formula is $sin(x+y)-sin(x-y)=2cos(x)sin(y)$.   Here $x+y=n+\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $x-y=n$, resulting in $x=n+\frac{1}{2n^2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{2n^2}$. So $a_n=2ncos(n+\frac{1}{2n^2})sin(\frac{1}{2n^2})$ which is the expression in the book.

Your error was in getting expressions for $x$ and $y$.